# Can Standard logic app upload a blob contain a folder

Tags: azure-blob-storage

Currently in consumption you can specify a new folder in a blob container when you create a new blob. [image]

In Standard you have to use the upload to a blob and I don't see where I can specify the folder path:

[image]

Comment: The links to the images are broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***In Standard you will get two option for choose an operation one is `Build-in` and second is `Azure`***

[image]

would suggest you to choose **`Azure`** Option you will get same list of action as you are getting in **`consumption`**

[image]

Here in `Azure-> create blob action(V2)`, you will observe same thing as in **`Consumption`**

[image]

***Note : choosing Action `Upload a blob Azure Storage` from `Build-in` won't give option for Folder Path.***

[image]